# How can sscanf read until whitespace or tab or newline

Tags: c, scanf

I've got some assignment on programming course I'm taking this term on C and got some trouble with using `sscanf` function.

The program is actually supposed to receive from the user a line of student's details at the following form:

```
<ID> <NAME> <GRADE> <AGE> <COUNTRY> <CITY>
```

We have some limitations regarding the form of each field, like the ID field has to be of 10-digit and not to start with 0.

**The important thing with the input is: the user has to write his details where are separated by tab (\t).**

So I have tried to split it into fields using `sscanf`.
I thought if I use `[^\t\n ]` then it will "understand" that this is one field.

The issue is with `sscanf`, here is my use of the function:

```
            // Parse his details
            sscanf(line, "%[^\t\n]\t%[^\t\n ]\t%u\t%u\t%[\t\n ]\t%[\t\n]\t", tmpStudent.ID, tmpStudent.name,
                    &tmpStudent.grade, &tmpStudent.age, tmpStudent.country, tmpStudent.city);
```

But when I'm running the program the ID variable "eats" the name field, and the name field is left empty.

How can I overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're reading just one line of input, I'm not sure you need to include any of the `\n` characters because there's going to be at most one of them at the end of the line.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I've added it to deal with corner cases. For example, if the user decides to insert only ID?

Comment: I'm not sure how much that helps you: if the program requires all those items, then the user either entered them or they didn't.  I recommend checking the return value from `sscanf` and verify that you got all six items.

Comment: How are you obtaining the input line? Are you required to use `sscanf`?

Comment: @SteveFriedl I have to use sscanf or gets...

Comment: `the ID variable "eats" the name field` - I don't think it's possible. Please show example input line and example short program that exhibits the problem, at best including `tmpStudent` declaration and with all the `#includes` and `int main()`. If you do `char line[] = "id\tname\t"` I think name shouldn't be empty. Maybe the input is separated by spaces not by tabs?

Comment: @KamilCuk For the input line: 1234567891      Dando 100 22 H H
The ID is: 1234567891100

Comment: What is the `tmpStudent` definition? Are you sure you didn't overflow the buffer? Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the full program, there may be errors in other places, while the sscanf invocation is ok.

Comment: @KamilCuk It's a global student struct. It's a temporary student used to split the fields from line and then check if the input is legal

Comment: Sorry, I may not phrased my request enough clearly. I am not interested in the description of what it is and what's is used for. I am specifically asking, please show me the `tmpStudent` [definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations) and it's type definition, ie. `struct something { blabla; blabla; whatishere; } tmpStudent;`

Comment: @KamilCuk ```// Create the student structure
typedef struct Student {
    char ID[10];
    char name[40];
    unsigned int grade;
    unsigned int age;
    char country[40];
    char city[40];
} Student;
 
Student tmpStudent = {0}; // Use this temporary student to check validity of fields received```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition in your question. So in your `char ID[10]` can store only a string of 9 characters max. You are overflowing the buffer - `1234567891` is 10 characters, so with zero terminating character it needs at least `11` bytes of space. What happens after that is undefined behavior. Most probably the 10+ byte overwrites `name[0]` and you are indeed seeing an empty `name`. I also tested in an [online compiler and your sscanf works...](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/HealthyEmbellishedGenres).

Comment: @KamilCuk I have to verify that every field in the input line ends with tab, and nothing else. Not newline, not whitespace.... How can I verify that using sscanf? And the field name may consist of whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get `sscanf()` right is quite an art, and I avoid it when I can.

But this seems to work for me:

```
 int n = sscanf(line, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%u\t%u\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]",
                tmpStudent.ID,
                tmpStudent.name,
                &tmpStudent.grade,
                &tmpStudent.age,
                tmpStudent.country,
                tmpStudent.city);
```

It's important to always check the return value from `sscanf()` to be sure that you got all six items you were asking for.

In this version of the format string, I've added artificial spacing to make things easier to read, you remove them for real use (of course), but it's based on the requirement that tabs separate everything:

```
"%[^\t]  \t  %[^\t]  \t  %u  \t  %u  \t  %[^\t]  \t  %[^\t]"
```

As far as I can tell, all you care about is a run of characters that's *not* a tab.